# How can I figure out bit/byte size?

Tags: verilog

I'm confused by bit/byte. I know that 8bit is equal to 1byte.

Then, in Verilog, if inputs are defined as

> input [31:0] start;
>
> input [31:0] end;

What are the bit sizes and byte sizes of these?

[31:0] can represent 2^32 cases.

So, I apparently thought that each input has 32bits, which is equal to 32/8 = 4byte.

However, the ppt says that

> "start/end are aligned to 8-byte(i.e., [2:0] is zero)"

Why are they 8-byte? And why does that mean [2:0] is zero?

Thanks.

Comment: The context is very important so what "ppt". I suspect the ppt is talking about addressing a memory where the addresses must be on an 8-byte boundary. In that case the LS 3 address bits [2:0] must be zero. (e.g. AXI when you do 64-bit (8 byte) wide transfers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ppt probably talks about byte addressing. The address of the first byte is 0, the address of the second byte is 1, etc.

When the ppt says

> "start/end are aligned to 8-byte(i.e., [2:0] is zero)"

it means that the addresses are multiple of 8, i.e., `start` and `end` can be 0, 8, 16, ..., but not 3.

If you represent multiple of 8 as binary number, the least significant 3 bits are always 0 as you see below:

```
0  == 'b00000
8  == 'b01000
16 == 'b10000
24 == 'b11000
...
```

so that explains

> [2:0] is zero